# How to structure a backbone application?

Tags: javascript, backbone.js

I am creating a backbone application which deals with user authentication and after successfully authenticating user loads the main app.

In the main app there is a main view which deals with loading menus and basic UI for app then router navigate to a page sub view which loads content dynamically into a container, the issue here is router navigate is called before base view is rendered and base view cannot find container to append content.

here is my appinit.js

```
/*global App, $*/

(function(){

'use strict';

window.Application = {
    Models: {},
    Collections: {},
    Views: {},
    Routers: {},
    Configs: {},
    init: function () {
        var token = Cookies.get("access_token");
        var router = new Application.Routers.Approuter;
        Backbone.history.start();
        //Check token to find if user is logged in or not 
        if(token!=undefined){
            //Load base view for app
            var appFrame = new Application.Views.Appframe;
        } else {
            //If user is not logged in load login view
            router.navigate('login', {trigger: true});
        }
    }
};

$(document).ready(function () {
    Application.init();
});

})();
```

My router file

```
/*global App, Backbone*/

Application.Routers = Application.Routers || {};

(function () {
'use strict';

Application.Routers.Approuter = Backbone.Router.extend({

    routes: {
        "login": "login",
        "logout": "logout",
        "products": "products"
    },

    login: function () {
        new Application.Views.Login();
        ReadyLogin.init();
    },

    products: function () {
        var productsView =  new Application.Views.Product;
        $('#page-content-data').html(productsView.el);
    },

    logout: function () {
        Cookies.remove('access_token');
        Application.Configs.Users.token = '';
        var router = new Application.Routers.Approuter;
        router.navigate('login', {trigger: true});
    }
});

})();
```

My base view file

```
/*global App, Backbone, JST*/

Application.Views = Application.Views || {};

(function () {
'use strict';

Application.Views.Appframe = Backbone.View.extend({

    template: JST['app/scripts/templates/appframe.ejs'],

    tagName: 'div',

    initialize: function () {
        _.bindAll(this, 'beforeRender', 'render', 'afterRender');
        var _this = this;
        this.render = _.wrap(this.render, function(render) {
            _this.beforeRender();
            render();
            _this.afterRender();
            return _this;
        });

        this.render();
    },

    beforeRender: function () {

    },

    render: function () {
        var self = this;
        var userModel  = new Application.Models.Users;
        userModel.fetch({ headers: {'Authorization' :'Bearer '+Application.Configs.Users.token} }).done(function () {
            self.$el.html(self.template(userModel.toJSON()));
        });
        return this
    },

    afterRender: function(){
        $('#page-container').html(this.el);
        //After appending base load products route 
        var router = new Application.Routers.Approuter;
        router.navigate('products', {trigger: true});
    }
});

})();
```

I have been stuck on this since 3 days, Please help.

Answer (score 0):

From my experience building backbone apps, I put all the navigation logic inside appRouter.

Try restructuring you app by transferring the various bits that you put in window.Application into the "" route and into appRouter.initialize. It might solve your problem. For instance something like this:

```
var AppRouter = new (Backbone.Router.extend({
routes: {
    "": 'home',
    "login": 'login'
},
initialize: function(){
    //everything you need to initialize you app
},
start: function(){
    Backbone.history.start();
},
home: function(){
//your initial routing logic (navigate to login if token is undefined)
},
login: function(){}
}));

$(function(){
AppRouter.start();
});
```

Comment: I am noob in backbone, can u please elaborate a little.

Comment: I'm not 100% sure what you are trying to achieve, so it's a bit difficult to answer your question + I don't use yeoman. What I can say is that when I build a backbone app, I try and put all the "routing logic" inside one router.

Comment: What i am trying to do is let my user login then render a base view(with app menus and layout)  with some sub views(some initial data) one after another, my problem is my sub views cannot find element in base view to append to because base view is not rendered yet, i.e, sort of race condition so how do i wait for my base view to load for init my sub views, any help would be appreciated. thank you

Answer (score 0):

If you are using many iife's in a global module pattern:

```
var router = (function() {
    return Backbone.Router.extend({ /** stuff... */ });
})();

var models = (function() {
    return Backbone.Model.extend({});
})();

//more stuff

(function(router, models) {
    var app = { router: router, models: models }; 
    //init inside the iife
})(router, models);
```

If you want to keep *everything* in one iife

```
(function(router, models) {
    var app = {
        router: router(),
        models: models()
    };
    //init in here
})(
    function router() {
        return Backbone.Router.extend({});
    },

    function models() {
        return {
            User: Backbone.Model.extend({}),
            Foobar: Backbone.Model.extend({})
        };
    },

    //etc...
);
```

But, this is messy, right? That's why bundlers exist :)

Comment: I used yeoman to bootstrap my app with these multiple IIFEs. Is it bad practice to write multiple IIFEs?

Comment: @Dharmendra It could be better. Even if you're using multiple iifes you're still appending things to the global scope that could be overridden by something else. Keeping everything in one iife prevents that.